# is there any specific jquery plugin which includes a combination of jquery slider & php paging?

Tags: php, jquery, slider

I have a products listing page that lists 3 products in a single line per page. 
So I want to put next-previous buttons on left-right side of this 3 products line.
So when someone click next, it bring next 3 products by slide-in effect.
Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Dynamic-Content-Loading) pretty easily.

The key deviation from the quick example on that link is that you would need to do ajax call to get your next set of content assuming youre using `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` in a db query for pagination. Of course in this case you would have to use a synchronous request as opposed to an async one because you have to wait for the response before you can actually load the items.

OTH, If youre not paginating a db query you could just load up all the items in a JSON data hash upfront and then build the html in the callback... more like whats being done in that specific example.